# Where is 'Keep Modified Files Open' Option in Visual Studio Find and Replace

Tags: visual-studio

There was an option of **Keep Modified Files Open** in older versions of Visual Studio 2022 for Find and Replace action.

This option seems missing now. Is there a parameter for it to be visible anywhere in system.

Edit: menu location to undo is here:

[image]

Comment: I can't believe they removed this option. It was so useful. I had it always checked.

Comment: luckily it's still possible to undo modifications on closed files

Comment: @SoftWar Only if you're working with source-control - if you're not, then it's easy to do massive damage using this tool.